# How can I find the location of exe that runs as a windows service in run-time?

Tags: .net, windows-services

How can I find the location of exe that runs as a windows service in run-time?

Comment: Could you please add more detail about what you're trying to do. Are you asking how an executable can programmatically determine its launch path?

Comment: In addition, if you want this done programmatically, what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET - `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` (others have suggested `Application.ExecutablePath`, but this requires a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`, which a service normally doesn't need)

Native - `GetModuleFileName(NULL, ...)`

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName works as well.

Answer (score 10):

Use a registry look-up:

e.g.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\' + ServiceDisplayName;
```

then read `ImagePath` value.

Answer (score 4):

Programmatically or with a tool?

In the latter case, I recommend using Sysinternals' [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx): it shows all running processes, including services, and one of the fields is the command line used to run the process, including full path.

Their command line utility, [PsService](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897542.aspx), can be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

If this is .NET, you want **Application.ExecutablePath** (if you're trying to get the running windows service's own application path).  If you're trying to get the path of some other running windows service, that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

If your executable attaches itself to a particular port you could parse the output from

```
netstat -ab
```

Probably not the most attractive solution though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using .NET, the most straight-forward way is to use Win32's [::QueryServiceConfig()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684932(VS.85).aspx) function.  This will give you the path name, the display name, and all sorts of other information about the service.

Answer (score 0):

For native windows code: GetModuleFileName(NULL...) in the EXE (not in a DLL loaded by the service, for example).

Answer (score -3):

Usually they run under windows\system32 even though you may have installled it on another drive