# How to stop a service in cmd only knowing the name of the .exe file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, cmd

I need to stop a windows service in a batch file without knowing the name of the service. The only thing I know is that the file running is called SomeServer.exe but the SC command requires the actual name of the service.
Currently I have to scan a config file and perform ugly string operations but I hope there is a smarter way.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
    'wmic service get name^,pathname^,state /format:csv ^| findstr /i /r /c:"SomeServer\.exe.*Running$"'
) do sc stop "%%a"
```

It retrieves the system name, service name, path name and state of the services in csv format. The list is filtered for the required executable name in Running state, splitted using the comma as separator, and the second field (the service name) is used to stop the service

Answer (score 0):

this may be helpfull
http://richarddingwall.name/2009/06/18/windows-equivalents-of-ps-and-kill-commands/

> If you’ve ever used Unix, you’ll no doubt be well-aquainted with the
>   commands ps and kill. On Windows, the graphical Task Manager performs
>   these roles pretty well, but if you ever find yourself needing to
>   resort to the command line to kill a process (e.g. for some reason on
>   the Vista machine I am writing this on Task Manager just sits in the
>   system tray flashing instead of opening), the Windows equivalents of
>   ps and kill are tasklist and taskkill:

```
tasklist /v  - equivalent to ps aux

taskkill /f /im ncover*  - equivalent to kill -9 ncover*
```

and there is also pslist http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx

edit:
for services use psservice http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897542.aspx

or use the method described here (using the registry) https://stackoverflow.com/a/298823/1342402

Comment: Unfortunately tasklist /v shows only the prosecces but not the services. There are far more processes running than tasks so I guess I have to stick to sc :(

Comment: what about psservice http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897542.aspx